# Are there Windows Compatible ROS nodes?

Tags: ros, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write a program in Windows that is able to send packets to a ROS node. It does not necessarily have to be a Windows node, just a program that runs on a Windows machine and can send ROS (linux) -compatible packets for another computer running Linux to handle/receive those packets via a ROS node.

**Does roscore (the 'Master' node) influence this in any way?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240368/are-there-windows-compatible-ros-nodes?/) by [doullylogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27490/doullylogo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publishing and subscribing to ROS topics is not just a matter of sending properly-formatted packets. Your program also needs to communicate with the ROS master to advertise its topic, and it needs to negotiate the topic setup when other ROS nodes want to subscribe to that topic. The [technical overview](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Technical%20Overview#Establishing_a_topic_connection) goes through the details of topic setup if you're interested.

Instead of running a full publisher on your windows machine, you can run a ROS node which bridges a simpler transport mechanism into ROS.

Two of the more popular approaches for this are:

- Encode your messages as JSON and communicate over a websocket to [rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite). (easy)
- Use [rosserial_windows](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows) to tunnel messages over TCP to the rosserial_server. (better performance)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sdcguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/33652/sdcguy/) on 2018-02-28**:
Hi I have been trying to do this Using JSON over rosbridge, But haven't been able to figure it out. I tried to just create a Python script on Windows and connect to the port that rosbridge is running on and listen for JSON queries. And it just didn't work. Is this the right approach or not?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-01**:
This question has already been answered. If you're having a specific problem, please ask a new question and include a description of your network, your code, a description of what you expect it to do and a description of what it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I use two Windows Home edition computers to run ROS nodes, which chat with each other.

Neither Docker or VM is needed.

[ROS node on Windows](https://github.com/Wei1234c/ROS_node_on_Windows)

---

Originally posted by [Wei Lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/34187/wei-lin/) with karma: 21 on 2018-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-23**:
+1 for this, as it's really nice, but it would be good to mention that your work makes parts of `rospy` work on Windows, not "the whole of ROS" (as much as that is a thing).